# Uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I got a task: research $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty~e^{-nx^2}\sin nx$$    for a uniform convergence. I see that  $ \sup_{x\in X} |f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0 $ when $x\ne0$. But what I must do when $x=0$?

Comment: Check what do all the terms equal for $x=0$.

Comment: @quid series is diverge in this case

Comment: No, it does not. With $f_{k}$ you denote the partial sum? You could try computing the extremal points for the function $g_{n}(x)=\exp(-nx^2)\sin(nx)$. These points will be dependent on $n$. So you can estimate for every $n$ by the maximum and see, if it converges to zero for $k\rightarrow\infty$ (not $n$), its confusing if you have the same letters))...

Comment: It seems you did not really do what I suggest. :-) What is the 7th term?

Comment: @quid emm, maybe $0$? )

Comment: Well, last time I checked sin 0 = 0. So I'd think so. :-)

Comment: @quid :-) i need more sleep)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the series were uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$, then we would have $a_n:=\sup_{x\in [0,1]}e^{-nx^2}|\sin(nx)|\to 0$.

But $a_n\geqslant e^{-n\cdot n^{-2}}|\sin(1)|=e^{-1/n}|\sin(1)|\geqslant |\sin(1)|/2$ for $n$ large enough.